# HackerRank Missing Numbers

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I am trying to solve a task in this website here is the [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/missing-numbers/forum)

**Sample Input**

> 10
>
> 203 204 205 206 207 208 203 204 205 206
>
> 13
>
> 203 204 204 205 206 207 205 208 203 206 205 206 204

Sample Output

> 204 205 206

**Explanation**

> 204 is present in both arrays. Its frequency in A is 2, while its
>   frequency in B is 3. Similarly, 205 and 206 occur twice in A, but
>   thrice in B. So, these three numbers are our output. The rest of the
>   numbers have the same frequency in both lists.

There are 4 test cases out of 4 cases I have passed 0th,2nd and 3rd test cases but the 1st test case gives me wrong output and 4th test case gives timedout error. Please suggest me good algorithm or logic to solve this task. PLease assist me friends.

Sorry for my bad english please forgive me.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> al1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int size1 = sc.nextInt();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < size1 ; i++){
             al.add(sc.nextInt());
        }


        int size2 = sc.nextInt();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < size2 ; i++){
             al1.add(sc.nextInt());
        }

        Iterator<Integer> ir = al.iterator();
        while(ir.hasNext()){

            int num = ir.next();
            System.out.println("Number"+num);
            if( al1.contains(num) ){
                System.out.println("Before removing number from second arraylist : "+ al1);
                al1.remove(new Integer(num));
                System.out.println("After removing number from second arraylist : "+ al1);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(al1);
        for(int i : al1)
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}
```

**Here is my output:**

```
    Number203
Before removing number from second arraylist : [203, 204, 204, 205, 206, 207, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [204, 204, 205, 206, 207, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
Number204
Before removing number from second arraylist : [204, 204, 205, 206, 207, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [204, 205, 206, 207, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
Number205
Before removing number from second arraylist : [204, 205, 206, 207, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [204, 206, 207, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
Number206
Before removing number from second arraylist : [204, 206, 207, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [204, 207, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
Number207
Before removing number from second arraylist : [204, 207, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [204, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
Number208
Before removing number from second arraylist : [204, 205, 208, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [204, 205, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
Number203
Before removing number from second arraylist : [204, 205, 203, 206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [204, 205, 206, 205, 206, 204]
Number204
Before removing number from second arraylist : [204, 205, 206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [205, 206, 205, 206, 204]
Number205
Before removing number from second arraylist : [205, 206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [206, 205, 206, 204]
Number206
Before removing number from second arraylist : [206, 205, 206, 204]
After removing number from second arraylist : [205, 206, 204]
204 205 206
```

Comment: Please sincerely mention the reason before down voting the problem. It's my sincere request.

Comment: bad English is not bad. Sinserity is not excuse. To help us help you, show a testcase which your code fails--expected and actual output.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B912ghT5m4YSTzc1dFktNWtPdUU

here are the input and output files of 1st test case.

Comment: You don't seem to be removing duplicates in the result.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a test case. Make it easy to read and understand your problem.

Comment: Mr Joachim Isaksson i'm reading the first arraylist number and if the number contains in second arraylist i'm deleting the first occurrence of number in second arraylist..

Comment: @BunnyJoel Yes, however `1` in A and `1 1 1` in B would result in the output `1 1` which is wrong (unless I just need more coffee)

Comment: Have a cup of coffee Mr. Joachim Isaksson. I partially coded and don't know how to complete the task. Please forgive if there is any mistakes in my english.

Comment: Mr. Sasha Salauyou here is the 0th test case. If you think you are the knowledgeable person and my question is inappropriate please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use ArrayList, a simple way to solve this would be something like:

```
for (Integer i : al) { // This loops through the array.
    al1.remove(i);
}

// Now al1 have the desired elements, now all you have to do is put them in order.
```

It's not the most efficient, but it **is** the simplest code I can think about right now.

**NOTE:** I would use removeAll, but I'm not really sure about what it does with duplicates.